# avoid show image "This site can't load Google Maps correctly" appears

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make it appear when one of the messages "This site can not load Google Maps correctly" shows one image or another. Do you know any way to get this error? or, failing that, hide the image?

I do not think it's relevant, but I'm working with Ionic
 
I appreciate your help, greetings.

Comment: Google Maps API is no longer free. But you can still use the Embed API which is free for most cases. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

Comment: Yes i know it's not free. But i need to hide the image when the error appears

Comment: This is called [degraded experience](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages?utm_source=maps_js&utm_medium=degraded&utm_campaign=billing#api-key-and-billing-errors), this can occur if you don't include an API Key, or did not enable your billing account, or reached your self-imposed usage cap.